# IP-protect specific path/url in Azure WebApp

Tags: azure, authentication

I have a MVC webapp which use Azure B2C for authentication. I want to display a part of this app (https://url/x/y) on info displays (digital signage). To avoid auth timeout etc i have this views without authentication. Is it possible to restrict ONLY this url based on IP so it is just viewable on our office?
Of course I can move this part to another webapp, but hope to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

You decide which parts (controllers, methods) of your app require user security context to be present and which not. If a request arrives at a method which refuses to handle it (responds with 401) because it requires an authenticated users, the OWIN (or authentication middleware) will kick in and initiate authentication to B2C. If the method responds with 200, no authentication will be initiated. If you use the AuthorizeAttribute to prevent access to controllers/methods by unauthenticated/unauthorized users, either remove that attribute from the controllers you want to allow anonymous access to or use [AnonymousAllowed] on individual methods if the controller otherwise requires authentication.